# recover from snapshot

Tags: linux-mint, lvm, data-recovery

I have snapshotted an LV named roa to a snapshot volume named ima, then accidentally removed A file, I need to recover A file from the snapshot volume like what Btrfs snapshot did, but guides on LVM snapshot around webs are just focusing on a whole LV recovering or merging, is one file recovering possible in other better ways?

Comment: Yes. For a complete answer please [edit] your question to include the name of the LV volume and its snapshot.

Comment: roa is the LV name. ima is snapshot

Comment: Pleae [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/482744/edit) to include this information.